# bitcoin-php library without downloading daemon ?

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm building a website that will use bitcoin payments. Now guy that i'm building it for requested that I mustn't use any API. I know I can download bitcoind and communicate with daemon with json-rpc but I found this: https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php Now size of daemon is larger than 100gb, can bitcoin-php library help me not download daemon or is there any other way to not download it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "mustn't use any API"? An API is how one program communicates with another. If you download and communicate with the daemon, you will use an API to do so.

Comment: by API here i mean like Blockchain.info api or Blocktrail API